# matlab get data from a matrix with data row and column indeces stored in arrays

Tags: matlab, matrix

given the data matrix and indeces arrays for rows and columns

```
data=reshape(1:9,3,3)
row_index=[1,2,3];
column_index=[1,2,2];
```

I can get result=[1,5,6] by

```
for i =1:length(row_index)
   result(i)=data(row_index(i),column_index(i));
end
```

How to vectorize the loop?

Answer (score 3):

Like this : ( using [*`sub2ind`*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)  )

```
indices = sub2ind( size(data), row_index, column_index );
```

Then,

```
result = data(indices)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering if there is any more direct way without converting the indeces.

Answer (score 1):

I also find a indirect way without using.

```
data(column_index*size(data,2)+row_index)
```

Comment: That should be `column_index*size(data,1)` instead.